# Stack Info button above UIView in Utility App

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I've started creating a iPhone Utility app (main view and flip view).  I want to draw some graphics in the Main view, so I dragged a UIView object onto it.  This works, but I find that if I resize the UIView to fill the Main view, it covers the Info button that invokes the Flip view.  Is there any way to get the Info button to appear on top of the UIView?  In IB?  In code?

Answer (score 0):

You could move the button into the new view.

Or, you could call [bringSubviewToFront:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:) on the superview and give it the button as the parameter.